# How do I read in a Csv file full of numbers into seperate arrays so I then process them

Tags: vb.net, csv

I'm trying to read a list of numbers into an array from a csv file as I then want to be able to output to a file all possible combinations of those numbers.

For example here is a list of the numbers in a CSV File

```
-8,-13,-8,-2,-4,6,4
-6,-12,-5,3,3,12,5
-5,-9,-4,5,10,13,10
-4,-8,-2,7,13,17,11
-3,-6,0,8,14,18,13
-2,-5,2,9,15,22,17
-1,-3,5,10,16,23,18
```

How can I read the first number in the list in a separate array to the next number in the list and so forth?

This is using visual basic

Thanks

Comment: Clarification: You want the upper left -8 in array1 and the -13 to the right in a different array2? Or do you want first row in array1 and second row in array2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file is composed of rows each of 7 numbers then you need to 7 different collection variables. Because you don't specify how many rows are present I assume a unknown number of rows and thus the preferred type of collection to use is a List(Of Integer) instead of an array. This because the List doesn't need to know in advance how many elements do you need to store in it

```
Dim col1 As List(Of Integer) = new List(Of Integer)
Dim col2 As List(Of Integer) = new List(Of Integer)
Dim col3 As List(Of Integer) = new List(Of Integer)
Dim col4 As List(Of Integer) = new List(Of Integer)
Dim col5 As List(Of Integer) = new List(Of Integer)
Dim col6 As List(Of Integer) = new List(Of Integer)
Dim col7 As List(Of Integer) = new List(Of Integer)

for each line in File.ReadLines("c:\temp\this_is_your_file_to_read.csv")
    Dim parts = line.Split(","c)
    if parts.Length = 7 Then
        Col1.Add(Convert.ToInt32(parts(0)))
        Col2.Add(Convert.ToInt32(parts(1)))
        Col3.Add(Convert.ToInt32(parts(2)))
        Col4.Add(Convert.ToInt32(parts(3)))
        Col5.Add(Convert.ToInt32(parts(4)))
        Col6.Add(Convert.ToInt32(parts(5)))
        Col7.Add(Convert.ToInt32(parts(6)))
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Line not matching the expected pattern")
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

In Excel you can use build in mechanizm "Menu\Data\Text to column". You can assign komma to seperate it to columns.

Or if you do not want to use Excel you should use "[open file for](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264163.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)" method to read data, ald use split() function to assing numbers to dim array.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Steve´s answer I provide a more generic approach with multidimensional arrays. This is due to we can see the input csv as a kind of matrix.

```
    Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines("E:\\MAtrix.csv")
    Dim matrixHeight = lines.Length - 1
    Dim matrixWidth = lines(0).Split(",").Length - 1 'Assume all lines have same length
    Dim matrix(,) As Integer = New Integer(matrixHeight, matrixWidth) {}

    'Go thru all lines of file 
    For x As Integer = 0 To matrixHeight
        Dim csv = lines(x).Split(",")
        'Go thru all csv of the line 
        For y As Integer = 0 To matrixWidth
            matrix(x, y) = csv(y) 'e.g. [0,0] => -8
        Next
    Next

    'Test
    For x As Integer = 0 To matrix.GetUpperBound(0)
        For y As Integer = 0 To matrix.GetUpperBound(1)
            Console.Write("[{0},{1}] => {2}; ", x, y, matrix(x, y).ToString())
        Next
        Console.WriteLine()
    Next
```

Prints:

```
'[0,0] => -8; [0,1] => -13; [0,2] => -8; [0,3] => -2; [0,4] => -4; [0,5] => 6; [0,6] => 4;
    '[1,0] => -6; [1,1] => -12; [1,2] => -5; [1,3] => 3; [1,4] => 3; [1,5] => 12; [1,6] => 5;
    '[2,0] => -5; [2,1] => -9; [2,2] => -4; [2,3] => 5; [2,4] => 10; [2,5] => 13; [2,6] => 10;
    '[3,0] => -4; [3,1] => -8; [3,2] => -2; [3,3] => 7; [3,4] => 13; [3,5] => 17; [3,6] => 11;
    '[4,0] => -3; [4,1] => -6; [4,2] => 0; [4,3] => 8; [4,4] => 14; [4,5] => 18; [4,6] => 13;
    '[5,0] => -2; [5,1] => -5; [5,2] => 2; [5,3] => 9; [5,4] => 15; [5,5] => 22; [5,6] => 17;
    '[6,0] => -1; [6,1] => -3; [6,2] => 5; [6,3] => 10; [6,4] => 16; [6,5] => 23; [6,6] => 18;
```